# Trying to style an item with a specific custom class with material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to manage a music playlist with a material ui table. And I would like to change the appearance of the item I am currently playing. At first I was juste setting it as "selected" but now, I have custom theme, and I don't know what I should overwrite to have the "selected" appearances coherent with the theme of my playlist. So, instead, I would prefer to add a class to my row "playing", and then, style my item differently regarding the class it has.

I did not find anything working to do so. When I tried to add my custom class into my theme, I got this error :

```
mergeClasses.js:25 Material-UI: The key `&.playing` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in ForwardRef(TableCell).
You can only override one of the following: root,head,body,footer,sizeSmall,paddingCheckbox,paddingNone,alignLeft,alignCenter,alignRight,alignJustify,stickyHeader.
```

So, I guess what I was trying to do must not be done like I tried to. I tried this :

```js
const StyledTableCell = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    borderColor: theme.root.borderColor,
  },
  head: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  body: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  "&.playing": { backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)" },
}))(TableCell);
```

How can I add specific rendering rules to a custom classe in material ui ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&.playing` should be inside of `root` to be applied to the root element.

```
const StyledTableCell = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '&.playing': {
      backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    }
  },
}))(TableCell);
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! That worked ! Thank you very much, I have been trying for a while to figure out how this worked...